# Reputation graph is auto-wrapping to the next line in Safari browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph, safari

The reputation graph which is shown in the [summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024761/2024761) of a user's profile seems to be going beyond the bounds and auto-wrapping by itself, making it overlap with the reputation text below it. This is happening on both SO and MSO. Here are a couple of snapshots.

**Stack Overflow:**

[image: SO]

**Meta Stack Overflow:**

[image: MSO]

*Note:* This is reproducible even on viewing other user profiles and not just my own. I'm using *Safari 5.1.7 on Windows7 Pro*.

Comment: Which browser? No repro on Chrome, Firefox, Windows.

Comment: @hims056 - Added those details in the question :)

Comment: I can see this on mobile with full site mode

Comment: @Bala: FWIW full site mode on mobile is not supported.

Comment: @hims056 what ? right now im in mobile with full site mode

Comment: @Bala: by "*is not supported*" I mean if it has any issue it is not supported by *SE team*. See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/187824)

Comment: Safari seems to be officially supported and I'm not using it on my mobile, so this does look like a bug, probably only in Safari for Win7.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ - Yeah. That's why we haven't closed this question. :-)

Comment: @hims056 well, looks like it's supported now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed specific to Safari - for some reason if there is whitespace between `inline-block` elements, it adds a few pixels of margin.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2014.2.11.1361).