# Unable to add space, dot and many other special characters in the "Other Flag" text box

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags

Something really weird has happened. I'm unable to add space or many other special characters like `[< , > .]`(many more) in the "Other Flag" text box. This is happening when I try to use the "Other Flag" option on both questions and answers. This seems to be a bug to me as generally all those characters are allowed in that text box. Here is a snapshot of that

[image: No space allowed, along with other special characters]

JFYI, I'm using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows7 Pro.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using firefox.

Comment: @devnull - I've no choice but to use all SE sites on it(office constraints). But it is thanks to that constraint that I get to figure out [Safari-only bugs like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220491/216721). So probably this might be one too :)

Comment: Sounds very unlikely that this is one of our bugs; seems more like a broken extension/browser/etc. on your end. I cannot reproduce it; I can add spaces and periods just fine into that box in Safari 5. Can you test disabling all browser extensions, if you have any? Also, maybe the same browser on a different machine (or at least as a different Windows user)?

Comment: @balpha - You're right. I had just 1 extension(ad-block plus) which was working fine till yesterday but it seems to have broken today. Disabling that let's me enter space, period and all other characters. I guess I need to report this to the ad-block plus team instead. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking.

Comment: ad-block thought that space is actually an advertisement so they decided to block it.